# Multiple Website's - VPS Windows8 (IIS) - Domainname on namecheap.com

Tags: domains, server, iis, windows-8

I have 3 domains on namecheap.com 
but i can only get one to work with my VPS.

I think from what i have read so far the solution to my problem is i have to change my host files. I Know where its located but i don't know what to edit in it. i Cant find the full guide for my problem.

So thats why i went ahead and turn to you guys.

Important information:

- Single website works (direct ip direct from namecheap.com to my VPS)
- VPS with really bad support. (they dont help much)
- Windows 8
- Windows server v6.2
- namecheap.com domain.

screencap namecheap:

[image]

screencap vps:

[image]

Ive tried adding a new ip and directing towards that ip. but that did not work.
I also tried adding in the hostnames (they were not in there first) but that also did not work once i 
 went ahead and fill the second domain hostname in side (IIS).

Ive done a fair amount of research about VPS before getting one. And from that successfully hosted "game" servers. but that was relatively simple compared to this.
I am just really excited about having a domain thats why i bought the VPS initially. But now i would love to have multiple domains. i already bought the domain names. i just cant get them to work with my VPS.

Before asking this i tried many things. Also some stupid things. 
+ Theres something odd about my ip list in (IIS) dropdown in binding settings. there are these values in it: 
somethign with allot of letters like this: `058a:0582::11a:bqqr:54fc:10ab`

And a complete different IP then my VPS that i never put in myself.

i will add any more info you would like and take screenshots. anything to help speed to process for you helpers out there.

Comment: Hi John Conde, Thank you for taking the time to edit my post :) - I guess being friendly with an welcome is not the style this website goes for :) But you did a good job making it more overviewable. ty.

Comment: Are all 3 of your sites using the same IP address? or do they have 1 per site (ssl bound to the ip)?

Comment: Hi Liam thanks for answering, Well heres an image i made explaining it. http://i.stack.imgur.com/xY68i.png - i have one VPS with 1 IP (dont know how to have more) so the question is how do i make multiple sites on 1 IP.

Comment: see i work with apache which in the config file you can bind by ip or you can use *:80 to bind it have a look here and let me know what you think. http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding

Comment: also try this: http://hosting.com/support/iis7/create-new-sites-in-iis-7/

Comment: on the link it says this: A name-based website shares a single IP address with each website on the server. You are able to make as many name-based sites as you wish with your single IP address. --- But it does not say how...

Comment: Ok i have got it working. i just messed around loads and got it to work with hostnames :) yaay! so happy!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Running multiple websites using the same IP address on a single VPS is very common.  I am basing my response on a few assumptions:

1. You have 3 different domain names
2. You have 3 IIS websites setup in IIS Manager
3. Each website points to a different webroot on the file system (although they don't necessarily have to)
4. Each website needs to run on port 80 (if SSL is required, then there might be additional configuration based on the domains and type of certificate that is used).

To run the three sites on the same IP address, it should go without saying that the DNS records for each of the three domains should be pointing at the same IP address.  These will most likely be 'A' records for each domain.  Once your DNS records are correctly setup, the next step is to make sure that the bindings for each of the three IIS sites includes the protocol, IP address, port, and (most importantly in this case) the host header.

I did not see it in the details of your question, but it is possible that one or more of your IIS sites is missing the host header.  If you are running multiple sites on your VPS, it may be a good idea to not use the 'Default Web Site' and instead setup three additional sites each with a host header configured in the bindings.  By setting it up this way, it allows you to use the Default site to test that your server is working correctly without affecting the other sites on your server.

Scott Forsyth (an IIS MVP) has a good tutorial video that explains bindings pretty well.  Have a look at his explanation [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/understanding-iis-bindings).  That should help you in making sure that you have IIS setup and configured correctly.